# Nodejs endpoint connection timeout

Tags: html, node.js, apache, nodemailer

I have created an endpoint in node that when called from a simple html page, it sends an email. Everything works as expected, I am able to click the button and send an email, however when I go outside of the local network, things go awry.

I am able to access all the pages, using an apache server, however whenever hitting the email button, I am faced with `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` and I cannot seem to figure out why.

I have set up my router to forward all traffic coming in to port 8080 to the apache server, and all traffic coming in to port 8081 to the endpoint `/sendMail`

The server hosting the pages was sitting behind a set of iptables rules as but I have since set the rules to an empty rule set, to no avail

For reference,

**mail.js**

```
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let multer = require('multer');
let cors = require('cors');
let url  = require('url');
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
let fs = require('fs');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));
//app.use(multer());

/**
 *
 * Function to hopefully send an email :)
 */

app.post("/sendMail", function (req, res) {
    console.log("HERE");
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
       service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'bodycentralprintingsite@gmail.com',
            pass: 'b0dyCenTral!'
        }
    });

    let mailOptions = {
        from: 'bodycentralprintingsite@gmail.com',
        to:   'justinbng36@gmail.com',
        subject: 'New Order ' + new Date(),
        text:    'Order recieved',
        attachments: [
            {
                path: req.body.image
            }
        ]
   };
   transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
        if (error) {
           console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        }
    });
});

app.listen(8081);
```

**clientside.js**

```
$('#Submit').click(function(){
    console.log("HERE");
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#Submit")).then(canvas => {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
//        url: 'http://192.168.1.23:8080/sendMail',
        url: 'http://68.228.250.168:8081/sendMail',
        data: canvas ,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(resultData) {console.log('done')}
        });
    });
});
```

Edit: The server that is hosting the web pages, is also responsible for starting the node server running `mail.js`. However when leaving the url as the internal IP in `clientside.js` (as is in the commented out url line) I am still faced with the timeout error

Comment: _and all traffic coming in to port 8081 to the endpoint `/sendMail`_: I'm not sure how you redirect a port to an endpoint, since it's all in the same Node server, why not use 8080? Or why differentiate router rules in your phrase? (And please tell me you didn't paste _real_ e-mail addresses, especially the one with its password...)

Comment: @StockOverflaw No, they're fake emails, I am not that careless, and are you saying I should just say `app.listen(8080)` and then change the url in clientside.js to `url: http://68.228.250.168:8080/sendMail` ?

Comment: @StockOverflaw also for clarification, by *ll traffic coming in to port 8081 to the endpoint `/sendMail`* is that I send anyting coming in to `68....:8081` -> `InternalIP:8081/sendMail` if that even makes sense?

Comment: For your first comment: sorry I based that on the description you made of the issue, I thought the mailing Node was the same that served the other routes of your API, apparently not. For second comment: maybe that's the problem, redirecting to `/sendMail` whereas you already define `/sendMail` in your URL (or maybe the rule doesn't play because you define `/sendMail` in the URL). Try redirecting `68...:8081 > internal:8081`, or `68...:8081/sendMail > internal:8081/sendMail`? Just an idea because I don't know routers being able to map URLs: I've only known mapping of IPs/ports.

Comment: @StockOverflaw I'm not sure I understand your second comment? I am already redireting `68...:8081 -> internal:8081` and then i just add `/sendMail` at the end when I query it. Also I edited the original post to hopefully clarify the scenario a bit better, my apologies.

Comment: OK that's what I was wondering. I'd say your issue lies in the router configuration, but apparently it's the same configuration for 8080 and 8081. To ensure whether it's Node-related: when calling the route, do you see `console.log("HERE");` being displayed? If not: remove all 3 `app.use`, start the Node manually, and directly call the route using Postman with an empty payload and no headers. Do you then see `console.log("HERE");` being displayed? If not again, then the issue lies before Node is hit, so your router (and maybe Apache intercepting?) is at fault here, not Node.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the time out because you aren't sending a response to the client after the email is successful. so the client keeps waiting for a response until the timeout limit is reached.

Try changing this line:

```
console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
```

to this:

```
res.status(200).json(info.response)
```

Also id suggest adding `res.status(500).json(error)` in your error handler